# comparing array.includes with database data by using If condition in javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
{
type:"fresh"
},
{
type:"marine",
},
{
type:"rank",
}
```

so my object somewhat look like this and i made a function
which i want to check type by giving if condition
so wrote a code like this

```
function test(req,res){
object.map((value)=>{
if(value.type=="fresh"|| value.type=="marine" || value.type=="tank"){
// do some condition
}
```

so I am putting all my condition in IF condition if and the problem is if there are more type condition then i have to do it like this value.type== "some"

- so i was trying to put all this type in one array like this

```
let testType=["fresh","marine","tank"];
```

and trying to call it in my if condition
as I know its work like this

```
if(testType.includes(true)){
// do some stuff
}
```

but how i can check with my database type
do i have to do like this

```
if(value.type== testType.includes(true))
```

is this possible i can mention all my condition and then check with database ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? BTW the data that you show up in the very first code snippet should be wrapped in an array...`[
  {
    type: "fresh",
  },
  {
    type: "marine",
  },
  {
    type: "rank",
  },
]`

Comment: i am giving rough idea how my data look like @decpk

Comment: What do you want to do when the type matches?

Comment: i just want to minimise my if condition by not giving to much condition inside if bcoz same code i am repeating again and again

Comment: How could you test `testType.includes(true)` when you know your array contain all string? `testType=["fresh","marine","tank"]`

Comment: if type match i will do other necessary coding @M.HassanNasir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) takes a value and checks if it is in the value. You are on the right track when you used `testType.includes()`, but you aren't doing it correctly. You need to check if `testType` includes `value.type`:

```js
if (testType.includes(value.type)) // Do stuff
```

Comment: thank you i was only aware that it takes only true and false value :D